# multiple variables tidyr pivoting

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

I Have a `tibble` called `test` looking like this:

```
   date       series_id.x  value.x series_id.y value.y
   <date>     <chr>        <dbl>   <chr>       <dbl>
 1 2020-08-03 ABC           0.1      ^FHJ          0.078
 2 2020-07-27 ABC           0.105    ^FHJ          0.093
 3 2020-07-20 ABC           0.12     ^FHJ          0.105
 4 2020-07-13 ABC           0.145    ^FHJ          0.125
 5 2020-07-06 ABC           0.15     ^FHJ          0.128
 6 2020-06-29 ABC           0.15     ^FHJ          0.125
 7 2020-06-22 ABC           0.155    ^FHJ          0.14 
 8 2020-06-15 ABC           0.175    ^FHJ          0.155
 9 2020-06-08 ABC           0.17     ^FHJ          0.153
10 2020-06-01 ABC           0.15     ^FHJ          0.128
```

I was trying to pivot this `tibble` into longer series of data, where `series_id.x` and `series_id.y` become `series_id`, and `value.x` and `value.y` become `value`, `date` column essentially remains unchanged (but actually can be used to do grouping as each date now has two series associated with it, i.e `series` and `value`)

I've read the `tidyr` pivoting guide on google and have tried a few permutations, none of them worked.

Typically I got:

```
test %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols=contains(c("x","y")), names_to="series_id", values_to="value")

test %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(-date, names_to="series_id", values_to="value")

test %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(-date, names_to=c("series_id", "value"), names_pattern="(.)(.)")

test %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("series_id"), names="series_id", values="value")
```

All above were failed attempts. I know I missed something, but it's not clear from guide whether my use-case is possible at all.

Comment: @akrun I have tiny-tweaked your solution and it worked, we just need to add a dot in front of `series_id` inside `names_to`. i.e. `names_to=c('.value', '.series_id')`; we could even change `.series_id` to anything we like, but we can't change`.value`. I think I need to read further for the meaning of this dot and how to use it. If you come back I'll accept your answer, thanks again!

Comment: you are right.  I didn't test it earlier.  Sorry.  The reason could be the `value` column name

Comment: not a problem at all! whenever you have time you can add back the answer I'll accept it, it was your work after all :) @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we may need to specify the delimiter which is `.`.  By default, it is in regex mode i.e. `.` can match any character, so we escape (`\\`).  Also, as there are multiple set of columns, specify the `names_to` as a vector of `.value` and the column name

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = matches('\\.[xy]'),
      names_to = c('.value', '.series_id'), values_to = 'value', names_sep="\\.")
```